# where can I find manual_reconciliation_view in odoo 9 (accounting module)

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

in the pic below I want to get the source code for the view of manual_reconciliation_view so I can use its techniques in my project, developer menu doesn't contain any items when I open this view 
to open it you have to open accounting module first and click on " Dashboard" then click on reconcile items as shown in pics below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://drive.google.com/a/lodigroup.net/file/d/0BzSA94_IwlAUM2ZNdC1LdnpZU3M/view?usp=drivesdk

You need to activate the developer mode in order to see this menu.

Best regards

Comment: Please check that you have permission as accounting adviser